# JavaScript Intellisense - Field of the same type as surrounding object

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, xml-comments

In an MVC 4 ASP.Net project I have the following JavaScript file:

```
Foo = function () {
    ///<field name="bar" type="Foo" mayBeNull="true"></field>
    this.bar = null;
}

Foo.prototype.test = function () {
    this.
}
```

When I type the period in `test()`, I get no intellisense support ("intellisense was unable to determine an accurate completion list for this expression").

If I remove the line `this.bar = null;`, I get full intellisense support, but `bar` has not been initialized to `null`.

If I instead change the comment's type to another type, e.g. to `Number` or to another declared constructor method, I get full intellisense support for that type.

If I change the initialization to `this.bar = 6;`, I get intellisense support for `Number` which seems reasonable.

The problem seems to be that intellisense is not able to match `null` to the `Foo` class, but only in the constructor method of the specified type.

**Is there a way I can get intellisense to work with the null-initialization?**

If I try out intellisense at the end of the constructor method, I get the following result:

The original variant gives me intellisense for `this`, but the type of `bar` is unknown.

If I remove `this.bar = null;`, intellisense tells me that the type of `bar` is `Foo`, but is unable to get its members.

If I change the initialization to `this.bar = 6;`, I get intellisense support for `Number`.

### Update

Bug report has been filed at [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/897250/javascript-intellisense-null-initialized-field-of-the-same-type-as-surrounding-object). If you can reproduce the problem, feel free to let them know.

Comment: Try swapping those two lines (maybe)

Comment: maybe `var n = null .... this.bar = n;`

Comment: @SLaks This does not break intellisense completely anymore, but `bar's` type is unknown. Btw, I have found out that the `<field>` declaration should be before any code. Not before the actual field declaration as specified in the documentation.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto No, same behavior.